# Need solution for embedding live stream on web page, with call to action or chat (with no sign in)

Tags: web-apps, chat, streaming, embeddable

I need a turnkey solution for a live stream with call to action and/or chat on one page of our wordpress site, which meets the following requirements:

1. I want all visitors to the webpage to instantly see and hear us speaking to them immediately upon landing on the page. And I want it work on all devices. And no plugins, no need to click anything or "allow" anything. In other words, I need a responsive embedded HTML5 live stream that loads instantly and allows the visitor to see us and hear us without having to click or "allow" anything.
2. I want to know when a visitor lands on the page so that we can address them live.
3. I want to be able to engage the visitor with a call to action. Perhaps even allow them to type to us. But at least be able to display a call to action button. Ideally a chat option too, which does not require any sign in or anything to "allow".

So in short, I need a responsive embedded HTML5 video stream, with call to action and/or chat to be able to engage each visitor as they land on the page. The visitor should not be required to click anything or "allow" anything in order to see us and hear us (nor should they be required to sign in to anything or "allow" anything to be able to chat with us if there is a chat option).

I've searched a lot for solutions such as web conferencing, webinars, live chat support, youtube live, etc., but I haven't found anything that meets our requirements. Anyone know a turnkey solution for what we need? Where we just configure it and then add the embed code to the webpage? Thanks in advance!

Here is additional info that was requested regarding budget and staffing:

We expect to pay something on the order of $100 per month if there is a turnkey solution out there.  But we're open to paying up to a few hundred dollars per month if we need to.  We're prepared with 4 or 5 staff to take turns broadcasting and acting as the live agent to interact with the website visitors, at least during our operating hours (which may not be 24/7 at the beginning).  Note that we only need one staff person at a time for the live broadcast because the one live stream will be broadcast to every visitor.  We don't expect a flood of visitors at the beginning and it's okay if we juggle addressing the visitors with the call to action button (or address them together), or if there is a chat feature then it can be group chat as well (it doesn't matter if all visitors see each others comments).

Comment: I have a question about group chat here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/71676/14834

Answer (score 1):

[webcall.me](https://webcall.me/) does not require any sign-in and there are no plugin installations

You can embed it in less than a minute in your project, but probably will not meet all your requirements

It allows your visitors to call you on your phone directly from the wordpress website using links

The app has very slick design and it is free

Answer (score 0):

If i get everything right, you might want to see this application... Enter a chat room name and you'll be able to join in and chat with anyone that enters the room.

https://opentokrtc.com

If this is the kind of solution you're looking for, you might want to look further in the WebRTC technology.

Comment: Hi thanks but I don't see an option to embed this on a webpage and besides that it seems to require the user to (1) sign in and (2) "allow" browser permissions.  As stated, I need something embedded on my webpage which will allow webpage visitors to instantly see and hear our live stream and be able to interact with us (either by chat or at least with a call to action button that we can make appear while talking to them), and again without requiring the visitors to sign in and without requiring them to "allow" any browser permissions.